Accessibility Service not Capturing Updated URLs in New Browser Tabs on Android
I am working on an Android app that uses the accessibility service to enforce safe search. It works by detecting when the user makes a search/opens a tab on a supported browser, then redirecting the user to a new browser tab with the original URL along with the safe search URL parameter tagged on. However, I am facing an issue where the service correctly opens a new tab with the safe search URL, but when it attempts to re-run the checks on safe search compliance, it captures the old URL (without the safe search parameter). As a result, the service enters a loop of opening new tabs.
Here is the code responsible for enforcing safe search:
override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
    if (!isActive || event == null) return //Logic for toggling the service on or off

    val packageName = event.packageName?.toString() ?: return
    if (packageName in supportedBrowsers) {
        //Get the current URL from the node
        val nodeInfo = event.source ?: return
        val currentUrl = extractUrlFromNodeInfo(nodeInfo) //Code to extract URL is pasted lower in my post
        
        if (currentUrl != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: Current URL = $currentUrl")
            //Check if the current URL is one of the homepages to ignore
            if (isHomePage(currentUrl)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: URL is a homepage, ignoring.")
            } 
            else {
                //Check if the current URL is already a safe search url
                val safeSearchKey = safeSearchKeys[packageName] ?: return
                if (isSafeSearchActive(currentUrl, safeSearchKey)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: Safe search is already active. No modification needed.")
                }
                //If the url is not a safe search url
                else {
                    //Apply safe search and redirect
                    val safeUrl = applySafeSearch(currentUrl, safeSearchKey)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: Redirecting to safe URL = $safeUrl")
                    openUrlInSameBrowser(packageName, safeUrl)
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: No URL found during tab change")
        }
    } 
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: Browser not supported")
    }
}

Code to extract URL's:
private fun extractUrlFromNodeInfo(nodeInfo: AccessibilityNodeInfo): String? {
    //Check if the current node is an EditText to extract URL
    if (nodeInfo.className == "android.widget.EditText") {
        val text = nodeInfo.text?.toString()
        if (text != null && (text.contains("www.") || text.contains(".com") || text.contains(".net") || text.contains(".org"))) {
            return if (text.startsWith("http://") || text.startsWith("https://")) {
                text
            } 
            else {
                "https://$text"
            }
        }
    }

    //Traverse child nodes to find a URL
    for (i in 0 until nodeInfo.childCount) {
        val child = nodeInfo.getChild(i)
        if (child != null) {
            val result = extractUrlFromNodeInfo(child)
            if (result != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "extractUrlFromNodeInfo: URL found in child = $result")
                return result
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}

Code to check if safe search is active:
private val safeSearchKeys = mapOf(
    "com.android.chrome" to "&safe=active",  
    "com.brave.browser" to "safesearch.brave.com"
)
private fun isSafeSearchActive(url: String, safeSearchKey: String): Boolean {
    return url.contains(safeSearchKey)
}

Code to open new tab
private fun openUrlInSameBrowser(packageName: String, safeUrl: String) {
    Log.d(TAG, "openUrlInSameBrowser: Opening safe URL in browser = $safeUrl")
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(safeUrl)).apply {
        setPackage(packageName)
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK // Start new task
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}

Is there any other simpler way to force safe search I am missing, or dose anyone have a fix to my issue.
